# Adding a CALayer to MKOverlayRenderer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, mkmapview, core-animation

In iOS 7, `MKOverlayView` was replaced by `MKOverlayRenderer`. Before, I was able to add a `UIImageView` as a subview to `MKOverlayView`, and access the `CALayer` of the `MKOverlayView`. Now, without `UIView` gone in `MKOverlayRenderer`, I'm not sure on how to add a custom `CALayer` (I have a `CAKeyFrameAnimation` that goes through a series of pictures rapidly). How would I add a `UIImageView` into `MKOverlayRenderer`? How would I add a `CALayer` in a `CGContextRef` (used by `MKOverlayRenderer`)?

I tried doing it on my own, but it doesn't go through the images at all.

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGRect test = [self rectForMapRect:self.overlay.boundingMapRect];
// Clip the drawing space to the map rect
CGRect clipRect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];

CGContextClipToRect(context, clipRect);

// CoreGraphics' coordinate system is flipped, so we need to transform it first
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -test.size.height);

// Draw the portion of the image in the map rect

// CGContextDrawImage(context, test, [image CGImage]);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
sublayer.frame = test;
NSArray *radarImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)image.CGImage, image1.CGImage, image2.CGImage, image3.CGImage, image4.CGImage, image5.CGImage, image6.CGImage, image7.CGImage, image8.CGImage, image9.CGImage, image10.CGImage, image11.CGImage, image12.CGImage, image13.CGImage, image14.CGImage, image15.CGImage, image16.CGImage, image17.CGImage, image18.CGImage,image19.CGImage,image20.CGImage,image21.CGImage, image22.CGImage, image23.CGImage, image24.CGImage, nil];


anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
[anim setKeyPath:@"contents"];
[anim setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationDiscrete];
[anim setValues:radarImages];
[anim setRepeatCount:INFINITY];
[anim setDuration:2.6];
[self drawLayer:sublayer inContext:context];
[sublayer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
[sublayer renderInContext:context];
[sublayer setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558591/animated-gif-not-working-in-mkmapview-overlay-using-mkoverlayrenderer?noredirect=1#comment30789828_20558591. Hopefully someone on Stack Overflow will help us. Please let me know if you figure this out.

Comment: Maybe try calling -setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:zoomScale: on a timer to mark it dirty so your drawMapRect gets called again.

Comment: any updates here?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following code

```
     [[[self view] layer] addSublayer: sublayer];
```

and use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray.