# Animated gif not working in MKMapView overlay using MKOverlayRenderer

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am trying to display an animated gif in an overlay for `MKMapView`.  The overlay is created using the `MKOverlayRenderer`.  To animate the gif in iOS 7, I'm using the `UIImage+animatedGIF` category posted [here](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) on GitHub.

The image of the animated gif displays fine in the overlay using the category; however, the gif does not animate.  I have no problem using the category to animate a gif in a `UIImageView` but it does not seem to work correctly in a map view overlay.

How can I use this category to place an animated gif in a map view overlay?

or...

Is there a way to place a `UIImageView` in the overlay which might solve my problem by setting the `UIImageView` with the animated gif?

My overlay renderer subclass is the following:

MapOverlayRenderer.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer
- (instancetype)initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay overlayImage:(UIImage *)overlayImage;
@end
```

MapOverlayRenderer.m

```
#import "MapOverlayRenderer.h"

@interface MapOverlayRenderer ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@end

@implementation MapOverlayRenderer

- (instancetype)initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay overlayImage:(UIImage *)overlayImage {

    self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay];

    if (self) {
        _image = overlayImage;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

    CGImageRef imageReference = self.image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);    
}

@end
```

In my `UIViewController`, I am fetching the animated gif and adding the overlay by calling a method which contains the following code:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:radarUrl] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        self.radarImage = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:data];  //for animated radar image

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.mapView addOverlay:self.polygon];

        });

    }] resume];
```

Any suggestions on how to animate a gif in an iOS 7 map view overlay would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have done something like that for rendering weather information on MapView Do you want like that only?If yes then let me know i will explain you in detail.

Comment: @iosRider Yes, please explain in more detail or submit as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/jhurray/iOS7AnimatedMapOverlay

this is the best way to animate overlays in iOS7

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, can you summerize?

Comment: Does this allow animated gifs to be displayed and animated in the overlay?

Comment: Sorry about that. What you have to do to properly animate over a map in iOS7 is add an animating view to your MKMapView. You can no longer add subviews to overlays. That also means that every time the mapViewRegionWill/DidChange you have to remove and add it to the appropriate spot. The appropriate calculations are in the linked github project above.

Answer (score 1):

Because a map view overlay is having your draw in a `CGContext`, it won't animate -- that is a buffer which is drawn to and translated to view contents, as opposed to being a normal part of the view hierarchy. Unfortunately you will need to make use of `-setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:zoomScale:` repeatedly to request animations. This system is a bit less flexible than iOS 6 and before, which added normal views atop the map.

Comment: So how do I use `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect` for the animated gif?

Comment: If if this way...I think you should probably setup a timer and call that 'setNeedsDisplayInMapRect' every interval? and ensure a new picture has been drawn in your 'drawMapRect' every time.

Comment: @wdanxna So are you saying to use the timer to display each frame of the gif? Could you submit an answer explaining this in more detail?

Comment: Yeah, this could get nasty, since you will need to calculate the current `MKMapRect` to cover the visible part of your image, but when you ask for the refresh with `setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:`, parts of it may load at different times. Depends on how fast your render routine is.

Comment: @incanus I'm thinking it may be better to place a `UIImageView` into the overlay (if that's possible). That way I know the `UIImage+animatedGIF` category should work since it's made for `UIImageView`. However, I have no idea at the moment how to programmatically place a UIImageView into the overlay renderer. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that with the new iOS 7 APIs. They are geared towards drawing static contents into a context as opposed to using a view hierarchy.

Comment: @incanus Well there is a bounty posted for this question. So if you can figure it out, then you'll get some extra points!